# Accessing MYSQL on network

Tags: asp.net, mysql, networking, localhost

I made a program using ASP.NET and it uses MYSQL. Currently I can use it using LOCALHOST run from MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 2008. It saves the data on that computer. I want to create a network that all can use that program, but only save the data to ONE database. I wish I could explain better.  Can this be done using VISUAL STUDIO 2008?

Answer (score 1):

You should host your program on a server on one machine and use that to access it from all other machines. When you open the mysql database connection, connect it to just one mysql server using its ipaddress and not using localhost.

Comment: So for example, I would put it on COMP #1 and from comp #2-#5, I would run the program by going to IE and typing the IP address of #1?  And instead of using localhost in db connection, I would use the #1 comp IP?  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: you will need to use dedicated software to connect to the database.
http://www.navicat.com/ has a free version which is very easy to use.

Comment: Currently I am using Visual Studio 2008 and localhost to get it working on the MAIN computer.  But unsure what to do from there to get it work on the other computers.  Not sure where navicat comes into play.

Comment: When you say host on a server, can LOCALHOST be considered a server for a local network? OR do I have to install something like Windows Server on one of the computer on the network?

Answer (score 0):

just enter the ipaddress like 192.100.0.2 , port , dbname , username, password

it is just the same for any serverbased database

here is my connection string

server=192.168.0.12; user id=root; password=pass; database=some_db; pooling=false;

Comment: OK so "server=192.168.0.12; user id=root; password=pass; database=some_db; pooling=false;" line goes into the asp.net syntax, correct?  Do I run a copy of the program on each other computer? Or do I connect to the main computer some how?